# Get field type of product or variant with element api

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-elementapi

Trying to get type of a field (dropdown, checkbox, etc) to render those fields in app, there is all sorts of info available in `$variant->fieldLayout->fields` like handles, values, ids except type of a field.
Based on docs there is no property like `type` in `craft\fields` class.
Maybe someone knows the way how to get this type of a field.

Here is my element-api config for getting a product:

```
'api/products/<slug:{slug}>.json' => function($slug) {
  return [
    'elementType' => Product::class,
    'criteria' => ['slug' => $slug],
    'one' => true,
    'transformer' => function(Product $product) {

      $variants = [];
      foreach ($product->variants as $variant) {
        $fields = $variant->fieldLayout->fields;
        $fieldsSelected = $variant->fieldValues;
        $variant = (array)$variant;
        $variant['fields'] = $fields;
        $variant['fieldsSelected'] = $fieldsSelected;
        $variant = (object)$variant;
        $variants[] = $variant;
      }

      return [
        'title' => $product->title,
        'url' => $product->url,
        'defaultVariant' => $product->defaultVariant,
        'variants' => $variants
      ];
    }
  ];
}
```